# angular material theme issue with setDefaultTheme method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, material-design, angular-material

I build one web app with angular material. Initially i started working on only one theme. later my requirements is changed to use other theme in some UI components. When i'm trying to apply new theme i.e. "lime". But it's apply for toolbar.

The issue is with   `$mdThemingProvider.setDefaultTheme('indigo');`
If i remove the setDefaultTheme method it's working, But for that i need to change more code in existing files.

I need work around for with the default method and use other theme.

here is my [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/wee686dh5kAqImj40GCU?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the watch tag in your code

```
$mdThemingProvider.alwaysWatchTheme(true);
```

You have to add `md-theme-watch` in your template as well.

```
<div>
  <md-button ng-click="dynamicTheme = 'default'">Default</md-button>
  <md-button ng-click="dynamicTheme = 'altTheme'">altTheme</md-button>
  <div md-theme="{{ dynamicTheme }}" md-theme-watch>
    <md-button class="md-primary">I'm dynamic</md-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've updated your plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/dEIGT3y1l85TOH1bKdMD?p=preview

You can read the documentation here

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/04_multiple_themes